# Attribute Unavailable Auto-enable Return Key prior ot iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

Hello guys recently i am working on upgrading my application to iOS 8 compatible and i found a warning on XIB file on UISearchBar i.e. Attribut Unavailable Auto-enable Return Key prior to iOS 7.0.
Can any one have the idea why this warning comes.

And one more thing on that screen some time keyboard not shown when click on search bar.
Is this is due to this warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this too and got rid of it by updating the **iOS Deployment Target to 7.0** for all of my targets.  I had one target that was still on 6.0 which I had totally forgotten about.